# ASPX Accessing master page function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a function placed in master page code-behind from another ASPX page as follows.

Main.master.cs:

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...
    }

    public static bool test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Product.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" EnableEventValidation="false"
AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="Product.aspx.cs" Inherits="Common_Product" Title="Product" %>
...
<asp:Label id="test123" runat="server" />
```

Product.aspx.cs:

```
using SiteABC.Accelerate;
public partial class Common_Product : SiteABC.Accelerate.SerializePageViewState   
{
    private void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main cm = (Main)Page.Master; 
        test123.Text = "yo | " + cm.test();
    }
}
```

This results in a compiler error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0176: Member 'Main.test()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

What is wrong in this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `test` method is defined with the `static` keyword.  Here are some links to learn more: [Compiler Error CS0176](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcxt2bd(v=vs.80).aspx), [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @CAbbott, I believe it was just a typo, you can't actually define a method like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...

    }

    public bool test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error said it quite clearly, you can't access static methods with an instance reference.
You need to do it like this:

```
test123.Text = "yo | " + Main.test();
```

However, I'm not sure if it's the best practice to put methods like this to your MasterPage... You should create a new class and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Test so that it's a property

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...
    }

    public Property bool test()
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access static method using instance object.

It should be

```
Main.test();
```